# In R, how to read each Excel row as a new data frame or list?

Tags: r, excel, import

I would like to build an Excel file of input variables with their characteristics. For example:

```
Name                Mean    sd
p.ca.revasc         0.80    0.06
p.ca.pci_revasc     0.85    0.05
p.ca.defer_xrevasc  0.40    0.09
```

I want to import this sheet into R but read each row as a new data frame or list. How can I do this?

In other words, after reading, I would like to the object and element such as this: `p.ca.revasc$mean`=0.80 and `p.ca.revasc$sd`=0.06

Do you have any suggestions? I'm trying to Google this but I'm having a hard time even knowing what the correct terminology is to ask this question.

Comment: If your file looks like this it would be better to use `read.table` and split the resulting data.frame afterwards. However, I doubt that you really need seperate lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, read the sheet in. I prefer to save the Excel sheet as a `.csv` from within Excel, so

```
master_df <- read.csv("excelsheet.csv")
```

but in some cases it makes more sense to leave it in Excel format

```
require("xlsx")
master_df <- read.xlsx2("excelsheet.xlsx", sheetName="mysheet")
```

Probably the easiest way to do this is with the `plyr` package. If you can be absolutely sure that each row will have a unique `name` column, you can use

```
require(plyr)
data_list <- dlply(master_df, .(Name), identity)
```

Otherwise you'll need to define an index column which is unique in each row

```
data_list$index <- 1:nrow(master_df)
data_list <- dlply(master_df, .(index), identity
```

That said, I can't think of a situation in which you'd actually want to do this. Better in most cases to keep the data in a data frame, and do stuff with the data frame.

Comment: This does not lead to a list entry per row, but per column I believe: `df = data.frame(mean = runif(10), sd = runif(10)); lapply(df, identity)`.

Comment: Fixed to be correct. I try to use base R instead of plyr just once, and see what happens..

Answer (score -1):

You could do it in a loop, not that elegant though. Then you'll have one data frame for each row in the sheet.

```
dta <- read.table("test.csv", sep = ",", header=TRUE)

for(i in 1:dim(dta)[1]){
  new_str <- paste(as.character(dta$Name[i]), " <- data.frame(Mean = ", dta$Mean[i], ",sd = ", dta$sd[i], ")")
  eval(parse(text = new_str))
}
```

Comment: Using `eval(parse())` is a poor alternative to using a list as @DrewSteen suggests. If you insist on create separate objects, I would simply use `assign` in stead of `eval(parse())`.